# Lower case in section title

Tags: sectioning, capitalization

I am quite newbie in LaTeX. Following examples in other questions for using lower case in titles, I tried to mimic them without success, when applying it to a section:

I am working in LyX2.0.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{textcase}

\begin{document}
\chapter{X}
\section{Y}
\section{Introduction to A\MakeLowercase{g} compounds}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\MakeLowercase ...owercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings 

 l.17 ...roduction to A\MakeLowercase{g} compounds}

 The control sequence at the end of the top line
 of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
 misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
 spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
 and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Is this somehow possible to get?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) That message suggests you're using `hyperref`, which however is missing from the example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As egreg points out, the message comes from the `hyperref` package. You need to provide an alternative to the section title, such one that can be used in PDF Bookmarks:

```
\section{Introduction to \texorpdfstring{A\MakeLowercase{g}}{Ag} compounds}
```

Answer (score 5):

A general solution to the problem of chemical element names that should never be uppercased can be the following.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to provide mock text

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\element}[1]{\@element#1\@nil}
\def\@element#1#2\@nil{%
  #1%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\MakeLowercase{#2}\fi}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\element\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{X}
\section{Introduction to \element{Ag} compounds}

\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\element` is split into the first letter and the possible second one. If the second letter is present, it's passed to `\MakeLowercase`. The `\element` macro is then added to the set of macros that can give problems to `hyperref` when building the bookmarks, redefining it just to return its argument.

[image]